# How to integrate C++ tests into a sckit-build pybind module

Tags: python, c++, unit-testing, cmake

I'm making a python module based on [the official pybind scikit build example](https://github.com/pybind/scikit_build_example). I (and the example) have some unit tests for the python part in `tests`, that runs with `pytest`. In my case, I have some libraries that I don't expose to python, so I want to have C++ unit tests to check those. How do I do this? For instance, how would I go about merging the stuff [in this tutorial using gtest](https://matgomes.com/integrate-google-test-into-cmake/) with my module?

*EDIT:* reading more about this leads me to think that I have to build the tests separately and then run the tests. Which is totally fine, as I could have a different github action that does that. I'm having trouble setting it up with proper cmake files that would work with `pip install .`, when called from the `toml` file, and that would work with a `cmake` command. It seems that at the very least, I have to also separately fetch `pybind11` as a library, on top of what `pip` does. Not sure I'm complicating things unnecessarily.

Comment: As you have said in your edit, GTest unit tests are just a compiled executable with your original C++ library and GTest linked. I would separate the testing of the C++ library from the testing of the python library and configure github actions to run the C++ unit tests.